# Why does this character survive?

Tags: alice-in-borderland

**Warning: This question contains massive spoilers about Alice in Borderland: Season 2. If you have not watched this season to the end yet, read on your own risk.**

Around the beginning of season 2, while Arisu and friends are on the run from the King of Spades, Arisu stops and tries to help a badly injured (dying) young man. I thought that young man is Arisu's brother, as the scene gets inturrupted by a flashback to an encounter of Arisu's with his brother. A few moments later, though, the man dies, and Arisu and Usagi continue their journey.

Also, in the final episode, we see that Arisu's brother is present at Shibuya junction in a car, so chances are he entered Borderland, as well, when the meteorite struck.

Yet, after Arisu has woken up, he is greeted by his brother?

**How did Arisu's brother make it back to the real world after all? Was I mistaken about the identity of the dying young man on the street?**

Comment: I think it's that the other young man was dressed similarly to how Arisu in the flashback was, and reminded him of HIMSELF--not his brother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The injured young man was not Arisu's brother. Arisu probably tried to save him because he was still alive after getting shot. But after realizing he had just died from the wounds, Arisu gave up, and he didn't mention anything about him afterwards, so it's very unlikely he was Arisu's brother. Also, we get a close shot of the injured man's face, which is different from the face of Arisu's brother.

I assume you've mistaken Tatta for Arisu's brother in the flashback shown in final episode. It was Tatta who was in the driver's seat of a vehicle in the junction when the meteorite hit.